# Can I use Qantas Frequent Flier points to book flights with British Airways?

Tags: air-travel, loyalty-programs, british-airways, qantas, oneworld

Qantas and British Airways are part of the OneWorld alliance;
so air-miles/points, from British Airways get added to my Qantas frequent flier card.

I am looking to do a short haul flight from the UK to Ireland.
I have a fair few Qantas frequent flier points.
But Qantas does not offer any flights from the UK to Ireland.
British Airways does.

**So I am wondering if I am able to spend my Quantas points
to book a British Airways flight?**
Since flights from UK to Ireland are pretty cheap,
I suspect I have enough to just cover the flight entirely, if that were an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Qantas points to book reward tickets on partner airlines, British Airways among them. The [BA partnership](https://www.qantas.com/us/en/frequent-flyer/earning-points/flights/british-airways.html) offers both *Classic Flight Rewards*, where you use points to cover the entire fare, and *Points Plus Pay*, where you use points to get a discounted fare. This is covered in the "[Use Points](https://www.qantaspoints.com/use-points)" section of the QFF website.

As with all frequent flyer redemptions, you book the flight through the airline whose miles/points you will be using, in this case Qantas. Right on the Book-a-Trip screen, you should see the options for booking:

[image: QFF points option]

You can also ask Qantas for assistance with booking over the phone, but this incurs an additional 35 AUD fee.

Reward tickets are not always easy to get. BA will only offer as rewards the seats it does not think it can sell. It may set aside reward seats for its own members before making them available to partners. As such, you may need to do a bit of hunting for dates and times where seats are available. Make use of the "Flexible with dates" option if you are in fact flexible.

As a further word of caution, BA is [notorious](https://thepointsguy.com/news/british-airways-increases-fuel-surcharges/) for fees and carrier charges, not least on reward seats for partners. Sometimes, the "free" ticket is actualyl a terrible deal.